# Apache Solr - Which is the best way to handle commits

Tags: java, apache, solr, nosql

I have the following scenario. A batch process which is reading 'x' records from an SQL database (where X is in the order of 10's of thousands of records), transforming them into a SOLR document, indexing and committing to SOLR. So ...

1) Read from DB
2) Transform
3) Commit

This process is run daily. After a few days, the SOLR process always reaches the maximum amount of threads possible (1024). I am not very experience with SOLR, but I have a feeling that the problem is with the too many commits.

I was thinking of committing after 'Y' transformations (where 'Y' is not large enough to cause memory issues). Is this the best approach? Has anybody encountered this problem before?

PS: I am using SOLR 4. I am using Java as a client.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change solrconfig.xml in your deployment:

```
  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">
   ...
    <!-- Perform a <commit/> automatically under certain conditions:
         maxDocs - number of updates since last commit is greater than this
         maxTime - oldest uncommited update (in ms) is this long ago
    <autoCommit> 
      <maxDocs>10000</maxDocs>
      <maxTime>1000</maxTime> 
    </autoCommit>
    -->
   ...
   ...
  </updateHandler>
```

the `<autoCommit>` element is commented out. Uncomment it and set appropriate values for maxDocs and maxTime. 
Basically it says:

The commit command would be **automatically** issued after the set amount of time or number of documents.

You could specify only 1 of the 2 criteria:

```
<autoCommit>
    <maxTime>60000</maxTime>
</autoCommit>
```

If you want the search to be reopened after the commit then you might also want this:

```
<autoCommit>
    <maxTime>60000</maxTime>
    <openSearcher>true</openSearcher>
</autoCommit>
```

Comment: Thanks Madhav. Does this mean that I have to remove all explicit commits from my code?

Comment: Yes, you could remove explicit commits if you want to solely rely on the configurations of 'maxTime' and/or 'maxDoc'.


You could also retain the explicit commits in your application code. Lets suppose there is a management GUI application where some admin/business user might want to add few 'records' manually and want to see those records appear in search results on the press of a button. In such scenarios, it would be required to trigger manual commit from the "Add record" button in the GUI.

Comment: Autocommit  is working fine. I set it to 1 minute, which generally is enough time for SOlR to index all the 'records' I am throwing at it. Hence I have gone down from soemthing like 12,000 commits to 1 commit.

Comment: 1 week down the line and the usual problem has not represented itself. I can safely say it is closed. Thanks Madhav.